# Marketo Rest API - Update Leads using Id

Tags: rest, marketo, lead

How does one go about updating a lead using a lookupField of 'id'?  I attempted to perform an update but received a '1003 - Field 'id' not allowed' error.  Below is my request data for reference.

```
{
  "action": "updateOnly",
  "lookupfield": "id",
  "input": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "Company": "TestCompany",
      "NumberOfEmployees": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "lookupField" parameter needs to be camel case in order to designate the lookup field like this:

```
{
  "action": "updateOnly",
  "lookupField": "id",
  "input": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "Company": "TestCompany",
      "NumberOfEmployees": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

This error is thrown so that if lookupField isn't specified that the deduplication is not ambiguous is both id and email are included in the input for a lead.

Comment: Thanks kelkington, after I fixed the casing everything worked as expected.